# Check if a content contains img with specific class PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to check if a content has images but avoid any images with class `emoji`

This is my code:

```
if ( preg_match("/(<img[^>]+>)/i", $content) ) {
   echo 'Images is exists';
}
```

This code is searching for any image without filtering by classes.

I know that I can make something like this:

```
if ( preg_match("/(<img[^>]+>)/i", $content) ) {
    if ( ! preg_match('/<img[^>]*class="emoji"[^>]*">/', $content) ) {
         echo 'Images is exists';
    }
}
```

but I feel that I can make what I need without the need to use more than `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using regular expressions is a terrible idea for parsing HTML, I'm assuming the data you're trying to parse has a predictable format.

The regular expression that should do the job is:

```
/(<img((?!(.*?)class=['\"](.*?)emoji(.*?)['\"](.*?)).)*>)+/i
```

This will match all img tags that do not have 'emoji' in their class list. I'm using a negative look-around in there, feel free to read more about it here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Here's an example of the expression above in action: https://regex101.com/r/4Yx1Nb/1

**In most cases you should try to look for an HTML parser instead. Parsing markup languages like this is not a good idea.**

Comment: Thanks it's working but edit your answer and replace ig to i, thank you again.